# Person, contactPoint, and contactType

Tags: schema.org, microdata

It's the first time that I use Schema.org and Microdata.

I have several web pages, each giving information about a company.

Let's say I have following short-info:

```html
<div itemsope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
Company Name: <span itemprop="name">MyCompany</span>
Address: <span itemprop="address">Teststrasse 21, CH-8002 Zurich</span>
Telephone: <span itemprop="telephone">+41792565050</span>
Investor Relations: <span ???>John Miller</span>
</div>
```

where `???` is a placeholder meaning I don't know what to place there.

`Investor Relations` always displays a name.

I could write:

```html
<span itemprop="Person" itemscope itemytpe="contactPoint">
```

Is that correct? What if I also wanted to add `http://schema.org/contactType` to it?

As I am new to this, I am not sure what ca be nested and mixed together.

Answer (score 0):

You must put the property first, properties always start with a lowercase letter and the property you want is `contactPoint`, so the code if you want to give no other details about John Miller would be:

```
<span itemprop="contactPoint">John Miller</span>
```

If you want to give more details about John Miller then you need to nest http://schema.org/Person inside your http://schema.org/Organization - and use `itemprop` for each property of the person, for example:

```
<span itemprop="contactPoint" itemscope itemtype=http://schema.org/"Person"><span itemprop="name">John Miller</span><br>
<span itemprop="jobTitle">Marketing Director</span> <span itemprop="telephone">212 5430543</span><br>
```

Both google's structured data testing tool and the [structured data linter](http://linter.structured-data.org) are useful if writing structured data and allow a trial-and-error approach.